# How to ensure a new route hits correct middleware in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel 5.5 app I am working on and it has an existing route which serves up html ready to be rendered to pdf:

```
Route::get('wkhtml/read/{documentId}/{pageId?}', $namespace . 'WkhtmlController@getRead')
    ->name('wkhtml.read')
    ->middleware('wkhtml');
```

This all works fine and when you navigate to the page, it shows the page ready to be rendered.

I want to make a differentiation between the pages shown here and pages which are going to be downloaded, so I added this route:

```
Route::get('wkhtml/download/{documentId}/{pageId?}', $namespace . 'WkhtmlController@getDownload')
    ->name('wkhtml.download')
    ->middleware('wkhtml');
```

If I navigate to the url eg `app.localhost/wkhtml/download/123`, instead of showing the pages, the user is being redirected to the login page. Nothing else has changed, so it is a bit confusing.

The `WKHTMLFilter` looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Services\Document\Author;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class WKHTMLFilter
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request to one of the wkhtml routes
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // If it's coming from the wkhtml
        if (!Author::isWkhtml($request)) {
            return response()->make('Not wkhtml, not allowed here', 403);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The `app/Http/Kernel.php` has this:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'wkhtml' => \App\Http\Middleware\WKHTMLFilter::class,
    ];
```

The request doesn't appear to be hitting `App\Services\Document\Author@isWkhtml`, as I placed a `die-dump` there:

```
public static function isWkhtml(Request $request)
    {
        dd('here');
```

At the moment though, the request is not even hitting this filter.

How can I get the request to use the filter/middleware, if not like above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you plz add your app\Http\kernel.php  and App\Services\Document\Author ?

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI I added it, but to be honest, it doesn't even get as far as the wkhtml filter. Thanks for any help you may be able to give with this

Comment: Did you tried to use route group middleware instead ?

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI group middleware makes the request timeout

Comment: Could you join me here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207260/ensure-a-new-route-hits-correct-middleware-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out in Laravel there are exposed routes in the `AuthenticatedSession` middleware, I just needed to add my new route:

```
protected $publicRoutes = [
        'wkhtml.read', // existing route
        'wkhtml.download', // new route
        ...
];
```